# NextJS v13+ router.refresh() in api response? Validate axios status

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js

I recently deployed at vercel a simple app that creates products in a MongoDB Atlas. In development it used to work fine. If I remove `res.statusText === 'OK'` condition in production it works (how should I validate this then?). Is router.refresh() the convenient way to sync the UI with new data in NextJS 14? Thanks in advance.

/api/product/route.ts

```js
export async function POST(req: Request): Promise<NextResponse> {
  try {
    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser()
    if (!currentUser) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: 'User not authenticated' }, { status: 401 })
    }

    const body = await req.json()

    const {
      title,
      description,
      price,
      imageSrc,
    } = zodProductSchema.parse(body)

    const product: Product = await prisma.product.create({
      data: {
        title,
        description,
        price,
        imageSrc: imageSrc || '',
      }
    })

    return NextResponse.json(product)

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error: ', error)
    if (error instanceof z.ZodError) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Invalid request payload.' }, { status: 422 })
    }
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Internal server error.' }, { status: 500 })
  }
}
```

components/products/add-product.tsx

```js
'use client'

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

const router = useRouter()

const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/api/product', data)
      
      if (res.statusText === 'OK') {
          router.refresh()
          toast({
            title: 'Product created',
            description: `Product name: ${res.data.title}`,
          })
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    } 
  }
```